# Is there any way to get back the WoL command card in HotS?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Wings of Liberty, when you selected a unit you'd get an Attack button on the bottom bar that you could click and then click a unit/area to move and attack.  In Heart of the Swarm I can't find such a button and it seems you have to press `A` and click for this to work.  Is there a way to get the button back?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is indeed!

It's one of the gameplay options.

[image: Options > Gameplay > Enable Simple Command Card]